# Нюанс по методу StreamReader.ReadBlock в C#

Tags: c#, .net

Добрый вечер, господа.

В процессе работы столкнулся с одной проблемой. Использую метод ReadBlock (char[] buffer, int offset, int count) и после чтения определенного количества символов пытаюсь узнать текущее положение каретки в файловом потоке. Но метод возвращает число 1024 вне зависимости от количества символов.

Скажите, можно как-то с этим бороться?

Comment: `BaseStream.Position` может не изменяться при чтении через `StreamReader`, т.к. последний буферизирует данные, прочитанные из нижележащего потока. Возникает закономерный вопрос: для каких целей это необходимо?

Comment: В общем, проблема уже решилась, и Ваше утверждение проверил уже на практике. Но свою проблему решил по-другому: читаю определенное количество символов из с помощью StreamReader, получаю количество считанных байтов и храню это. Потом перемещаю каретку при следующем чтении, если это необходимо.

Answer (score 2):

Я так понимаю, Вы интерпретируете возвращаемое значение ф-ции ReadBlock как текущую позицию в файле? Это не верно, возвращаемое значение этого метода лишь говорит о количестве считанных символов.

Используйте Position в BaseStream StreamReader'а.

Comment: Нет, как раз я использовал Position. И интерпретировал значение свойства Position как положение каретки в потоке. Собственно, как потом выяснил, размер буфера потока при чтении можно задавать, но он не может быть меньше 384.